# Classic terminology in Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology

I am reading about the Veronese surface in Semple-Roth and have trouble with some of the terminology. In particular, I have not been able to find definitions for $\infty^n$ and 'apolar to'. Here are some sample sentences from the book:

- > Among the chords of $F^4$ we must include the $\infty^3$ tangent lines to the surface, lying by pencils in its $\infty^2$ tangent planes.
- > we obtain a representation of the $\infty^5$ conic-loci of the plane on the $\infty^5$ points of $S_5$
- > If $F^4$ is the Veronese surface, conics of $\varpi$ which are apolar to $K$ represent sections of $F^4$ by primes through a fixed point $O$ of $S_5$

Answer (score 1):

$\infty^n$ typically means that the family of solutions has $n$ parameters or, in modern parlance, is a $n$-dimensional variety.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, and $T=\mathbb{C}[y_1,\ldots,y_n]$, and let $T$ act on $S$ by differentiation:$$y_i(F)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}F$$ Then the definition is $g\in T$ is **apolar to** $F\in S$ if $\operatorname{deg} g\leq\operatorname{deg}F$ and $g(F)=0$.

A term to search for is **apolarity**.